# java.lang.Process Kill not done

Tags: java, eclipse, swt

I am creating a SWT Application which invokes an external executable (say abc.exe) in `java.lang.Process`. This new process is created on 'Start' button on my composite.

The problem is that if the executbale *abc.exe* hangs; my entire SWT shell hangs! So I thought of adding new button called 'Stop' so the user can easily kill the hung process, but since everything executes in a single thread I am not able to press 'Stop' also.

Can anyone tell me/show me how best way I can solve this problem.

Many Thanks, Tor

Comment: This all suggests that you're not running the process in a background thread. If so, the solution is elementary -- use a background thread.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to run the process in a background thread. The problem is you are running both your SWT app and abc.exe in the same thread. What happens, is the processes are taking turns with request/response and there is no response from the abc.exe process so there it is sitting there waiting--the same should happen if abc.exe is executing a long-running algorithm.

Comment: Other processes always get their own threads, but it's often common to make the parent's thread wait until the child subprocess finishes.

Answer (score 0):

Process kill is in fact unimplemented in java as it is EXTREMELY DANGEROUS